# A congruence involving generalized Lucas polynomials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, primality-test

This is a generalization of [this claim](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2624685/15660) .

Can you provide a proof or a counterexample for the following claim?

> Let $n$ be a natural number greater than two . Let $L_n^{(a)}(x)=2^{-n}\cdot\left(\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+4a}\right)^n+\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+4a}\right)^n\right)$ , where $a$ is an integer coprime to $n$ . Then $n$ is a prime number if and only if $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}L_{n-1}^{(a)}(k) \equiv -1 \pmod {n}$ .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNjcEOgjAQRO98BqddWBOqx3U_gY8AxdiUthtaIsb47xYTEy87OzMvmSAnw9Ug5WicnyF6O8zgaaQN5aWdHFmNbOzK87jbeQJ3Fk8qW6OmHRvtuEBqdkrZtS3yMuV1CaD45ipJWj046SgcDEEfr_A3s2cDOaSAiFzZ2xdIxYrsnS42ZKiL-KnGn71ErzHZXCLkDzoyO3I=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) .

I have tested this claim for many random values of $n$ and $a$ and there were no counterexamples .